# What's the music when Frieza powers up from base form to his final form in the dubbed version of "Revival of F"?

Tags: music, dragon-ball-z

I have seen *Dragon Ball Z: Revival of F* many times and I love the music that plays when Frieza powers up from base form to his "Final" form in the dub.

If anyone could point me to the song used it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is part of the Revival of F OST. It is called "Merciless Frieza". Do note that this differs to the DBS version of this sequence. You can listen to it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvoeZ9vO9FY